# How do I get a CSS class to show up in my javascript with my previous method?

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble getting this to work. The class works for my caption (Because there is only one caption tag throughout my HTML). It doesn't work for my TR tag because for it to work I have to use a for loop. Here is my code that works for caption, how would I get it to work for my TR?

```
window.onload = function() {

    var caption = document.getElementsByTagName("caption");
    var oldCaption = caption[0].innerHTML;
    var newCaption = "CAPTION";

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var text = document.createTextNode(newCaption);
    span.appendChild(text);
    span.className = "hoverNode";
    caption[0].appendChild(span);
}
```

Here's my TR section:

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    var newTR = "TR";

    tr[i].removeChild(tr[i].firstChild);
    tr[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTR));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you can create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate your problem? I don't think we have enough to go off of to present an answer.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/132608c610ac065c39bfd59a10b4f2cc That is what it looks like. See how the caption has the class affiliated with it. I can't get it to show up for all of the other stuff, hence why I am asking how to do the TR tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the same way as for the single caption. Create a span in the loop, and give it the class you want.

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    var newTR = "TR";
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var text = document.createTextNode(newTR);
    span.appendChild(text);
    span.className = "hoverNode";

    tr[i].removeChild(tr[i].firstChild);
    tr[i].appendChild(span);
}
```